# En HTML como poner a un botón un valor <option>

Tags: html

Tengo creada una página con una lista de elementos, que tienen el siguiente valor:

```
<option value="40.432905, -3.704264">Madrid</option>
```

Cuando se selecciona uno elemento de esa lista, esas coordenadas se pasan a una función() que se encarga de poner las coordenadas en el mapa de google.

Lo que intento es crear una página que, en lugar de tener una lista desplegable, he puesto un botón que al pulsarlo muestra una tabla, y esa tabla contiene otros botones:

```
<button class="myButton-1" onclick="Menu(DivL336, 'L336')">Selecciona una Opción</button>
<div id=DivL336 class=L336Oculto>
<table cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
    <td><span style="font: 15pt comic sans ms; color: blue">»</span></td>
    <td><button class=BotonMenuDespl>Madrid</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><span style="font: 15pt comic sans ms; color: blue">»</span></td>
    <td> <button class=BotonMenuDespl>Alicante</button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Gracias,

Comment: No entiendo que intentas hacer exactamente, rescatar el valor del select y ponerle en el value de un botón y luego al hacer un click en un último botón mostrar el valor del value del botón, ¿podrías explicarlo mejor?

Comment: No he querido extenderme mucho para no liarla que al final ni se entiende, jeje, he modificado el primer post, a ver si ahora se entiende algo mejor.

Comment: He añadido dos enlaces con paginas de prueba

Comment: Armá un ejemplo de tu código en jsfiddle o algún sitio similar. Nadie va a descargar los archivos de wetransfer.

Comment: No se que problema hay con esa pagina, si hay algun problema me gustaría saberlo para no seguir utilizándola. he estado probando paginas como la que me dices, pero no me aclaro, y no me sale nada, dejo el link de mi cuenta de google, espero que de aqui no exista problemas https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QfvUFPLoMXN3_CY6WDUfGAf5UIkyYtTz si se quiere se puede descargar, si no se puede ver el codigo, si hay algun problema me lo decis,

Comment: he puesto también en el primer post el código en jsfiddle, pero no se si esta bien porque al ejecutarlo me da un error que no entiendo

Answer (score 1):

No se cómo es la `function` que tenés creada, pero los botones pueden tener nombre y valor.

```
<button type="button" class="BotonMenuDespl" name="nombre" value="40.432905, -3.704264">Madrid</button>
```

El nombre seguramente te convenga que sea igual al del `select` que tenés creado.

Comment: Hola, he puesto un enlace nuevo con el código completo del archivo botones, no termina de pillar el valor de las coordenadas. Al final del código he puesto un script con el que intento una vez pulsado un botón que se oculten todos, podríais echarle un vistazo que tampoco termina de ocultarlos.

Comment: Lo de ocultar el boton una vez que se pulse creo que ya lo hace con **onclick**,   
`<button type="button" class="BotonMenuDespl" name="href" value="40.432905, -3.704264" onclick="Menu(DivL336, 'L336')">Madrid</button>`   
pero no se si por culpa del onclick no toma el valor de las coordenadas, el caso es que antes de ponerlo tampoco conseguía que se mostrase el mapa.